# Efficient getting a pair of coordinates with the shortest distance from array of coordinates using Javascript

Tags: javascript, key, coordinates, distance

I have a several x-y coordinates stored in an two arrays, one for source object, one for target :

```
var sourcePoints = [
  {
    x: 20,
    y: 11
  }, {
   ...
  }, {
    x: 10
    y: 6
  }
];

var targetPoints = [
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 71
  }, {
   ...
  }, {
    x: 22
    y: 8
  }
];
```

Now I would like to select only some of the coordinates from the source array, some of the points from the target array (some combinations does not make any sense according to situation) and compute the distance between them.

```
coordinatePairs = [
  {
    [1,4] : computeDistance(sourcePoints[1],targetPoints[4])
  },{
     ...
  }
];
```

Now I wonder  how can I effective get those coordinates, with the shortest distance. Do I need to store those coordinate-pairs in an array ?

Comment: Your coordinate pairs data structure isn't legal.  You can't have `[1,4]` as the property name on an object.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking?  Are you asking how to calculate the distance between two points?  Or, how to calculate the distance between all possible pairs and then find only the closest N points?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the two points with the shortest distance, you could use something like this:

```
var minDist2 = Infinity;
var res = [];
for (var i = 0, max_i = sourcePoints.length; i < max_i; i++) {
    var sourcePoint = sourcePoints[i];
    for (var k = 0, max_k = targetPoints.length; k < max_k; k++) {
        var targetPoint = targetPoints[k];
        var dx = targetPoint.x - sourcePoint.x;
        var dy = targetPoint.y - sourcePoint.y;
        var dist2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        if (minDist2 > dist2) {
            minDist2 = dist2;
            res = [i, k];
        }
    }  
}
```

Note, that this won't calculate the actual distance of the points but the distance^2, so that you have one less operation (squareroot), which might speed things up a little.